# Average value of bytes

Tags: java, image, arrays, average

I have such a problem. I want to make "average" image from the few diffirent. my idea was to load them to BufferImage sequentially, sum values in each bit, and than just divide by number of photos. The problem is that i can't divide byte[][] by number. What am i doing wrong, or what is the proper way to do this?

```
File[] others = getOtherImageFiles(file);
byte[][] pixels = new byte[300][];
List<byte[][]> pixelsList = new ArrayList<byte[][]>();
for (int i = 0; i < others.length; i++) {
  try {
    img = ImageIO.read(others[i]);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
  for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
    pixels[x] = new byte[img.getHeight()];
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
      pixels[x][y] = (byte) (img.getRGB(x, y));
    }
  }
  pixelsList.add(pixels);
}
byte[][] pixelsSum = new byte[300][];
for (int i = 0; i < pixelsList.size(); i++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
      pixelsSum[x][y] += pixelsList.get(i)[x][y];
    }
  }
}
for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
    pixelsSum[x][y]/10;
  }
}
}
```

i want to use them as a face comparer and the point is to create a scheme of faces.

Comment: The line `pixelsSum[x][y]/10;` has no effect.  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: yeah i know, compilator says that it is wrong, i want to divide there value in byte of image to get average value. previously i summed this value ten times to get sum from all ten images, and now i want to divide it by ten to get average.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You did the division by 10, but you never wrote the result back into the `pixelsSum` array, so the result is lost. You need to do:

```
pixelsSum[x][y] = pixelsSum[x][y] / 10;
```

or in shorthand:

```
pixelsSum[x][y] /= 10;
```

Another problem you will run into is that each `byte` in Java (or any other language) can only hold values between 0 and 255. So if you have a bytes `x = 255, y = 1`, `x + y` will turn out to be 0. When you add up 10 images, it will almost certainly go over the 255 limit. I suggest changing pixelsSum from `byte[][]` to `int[][]`, and then turn it back to bytes after you do the division.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this set of loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pixelsList.size(); i++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
      pixelsSum[x][y] += pixelsList.get(i)[x][y];
    }
  }
}
```

you should put the `pixelsList` reference in the middle:

```
for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pixelsList.size(); i++) {
      pixelsSum[x][y] += pixelsList.get(i)[x][y];
    }
    pixelsSum[x][y] /= pixelsList.size();
  }
}
```

This should calculate the average immediately rather than looping through the `pixelsSum` array again.  Note also the use of the `/=` operator which performs both division and assignment compared with the `/` operator which is limited to division in the context of numbers.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Of course it was my foult, i've fought that these syntax error was becose of bytes couldn't be divided by integers.